# Android resource linking failed (not found any solution)

Tags: android, android-drawable, aapt2

I have an "Android resource linking failed" problem on my Android project. I have tried every solution that I found on the internet but nothing happened. This problem occurred after I changed the image file on the drawable directory. How can I fix this problem?

My errors :

> C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:35: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:48: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:91: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:143: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:157: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout\nav_header_drawer.xml:2: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\activity_splash.xml:2: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:35: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:48: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:91: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:144: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:158: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-sw600dp\nav_header_drawer.xml:2: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\activity_splash.xml:2: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:35: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:48: error: resource drawable/loc_buton_selector (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/loc_buton_selector) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:91: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:143: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\fragment_gonder_konum.xml:157: error: resource drawable/rounded_layout (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/rounded_layout) not found.
>   C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\src\main\res\layout-mdpi\nav_header_drawer.xml:2: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.tsg.loc.locfly:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.
>   Command: C:\Users\emre.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\fe3f8ef29de101fc5b6c9b7eb921f52a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
>           C:\Users\emre\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\build\intermediates\merged_manıfests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.tsg.loc.locfly\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\

C:\Users\emre\AndroidStudioProjects\LocFly\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
    Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

build.gradle():

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tsg.loc.locfly"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
   release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}



}


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

//circle image view
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

buil.gradle(project):

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my drawables:
[image: my drawables]

Comment: In android studio go to  File-> invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: Adding to it do a `File->Sync project with Gradle Files`

Comment: If you have errors in one of your drawables. I see them all xml drawables then building fails. Make sure you have no syntax errors in your drawables.

Comment: @AanalShah i did but same error.

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. i havent changed the drawable files but ilklogo.png. There wasnt a problem . i dont know why but problem occured sudddenly.

Comment: @ASN same error again

Comment: Is this your package name? com.tsg.loc.locfly? I think your issues could be there

Comment: @NaszNjokaSr. yes it is . i checked package name its same in manifest, and gradles files

Comment: You might want to check out this one :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676954/gradle-error-android-resource-linking-failed/54093968#54093968

Answer (score 0):

Can you locate the resource file 'R' in one of the java subfolders of your project at all? 
Seems like the location of the resourc file cannot be determined- I had the exact same problem just recently. If you cant locate 'R', it might be deleted off and that could be why there is a linking error.

If you cant locate it, try: 
**Build -> Clean Project** (that cleans the gradle file)

Alternatively: 
**File->Invalidate Caches** (and then sync the project with gradle files)

Give these a go and see if it changes anything. It may restore the resource file. If not, I suggest creating a new project and copying and pasting the code from the 'old' project into the new version, so you can make sure the resource file is restored and it should eliminate the linking error, too. You would need to re create all xml files and java classes, but depending on the size of your project it might be faster than trying to restore the resource file.